# Frame resets when label or text change

Tags: java

I am currently having some problem in some javaFrame application. It is a simple game where the ball is running around and there is one button which starts and stops the ball. The problem is whenever i change the text of a label or a button while the ball is running the frame resets(the ball is resetting where it was in the first place) and i don't want that to happen. I created the frame and the panel by dragging from the side(i did not write code to create frame and panels). I don't know all the rules in this site and i don't know if it is permissible but i could not find any ways to show this to you so i linked 2 short youtube videos at the end so you can see what it is(i apologize for that).

## What i did in frame:

1. Created 2 panels.
2. Added a button to panel1(upper one) and added ball image on top of it.
3. Added 2 buttons on panel2(lower one) which are Start/Stop and changeLabel.

## My NewJFrame Class:

```
package view;

import controller.BallAction;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private BallAction ba;
    private boolean isBallRolling = false;
    private int labelAsciiValue = 65;

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        ba = new BallAction(ball);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        ball = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Ball Game");

        ball.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/top.png"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addComponent(ball, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(515, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(ball, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(291, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Start");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Change Label");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(35, 35, 35)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 94, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(85, 85, 85)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(107, 107, 107)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(23, 23, 23)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    //Start-Stop Button
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(isBallRolling){
            ba.stop();
            jButton2.setText("Start");
            isBallRolling = false;
        }
        else{
            ba.start();
            jButton2.setText("Stop");
            isBallRolling = true;
        }
    }                                        
    //Change Label Button
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf((char)(labelAsciiValue++)));
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton ball;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

## My BallAction Class:

```
package controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BallAction {

    private Timer time;
    private final ClockListener clock = new ClockListener();
    private JButton ball;

    public BallAction(JButton ball){
        this.ball=ball;
        time = new Timer(20,clock);
    }

    public void start(){
        time.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        time.stop();
    }

    //If ball.x <= panel.x go right else ball.x = 0.
    public void update(){
        if(ball.getLocation().x<=ball.getParent().getSize().width-100)
            ball.setLocation(ball.getLocation().x+5,ball.getLocation().y);
        else{
            ball.setLocation(0,ball.getLocation().y);
        }
    }

    private class ClockListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }   
    }
}
```

Frame without changing anything : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yC_8tyUmal0

Frame with changing the text : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGvhCnRRTtw

## EDIT:

If i create the frame on my own it works fine.

Why is that please help me thank you.

## My Own Frame:

```
package ballgame0;

import controller.BallAction;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BallGame0 {

    private static boolean isBallRunning = false;
    private static int labelAsciiValue = 65;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000,800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel= new JPanel(null);
        frame.add(panel);

        JLabel changeLabel = new JLabel();
        changeLabel.setSize(100,50);
        changeLabel.setLocation(500,650);
        changeLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 36));

        JButton buttonLabel = new JButton("Change Label");
        buttonLabel.setSize(150,40);
        buttonLabel.setLocation(300,650);

        JButton button = new JButton("asd");
        button.setSize(70,70);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Start");
        button1.setSize(100,60);
        button1.setLocation(100,650);

        panel.add(changeLabel);
        panel.add(buttonLabel);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(button1);
        BallAction ba = new BallAction(button);

        ActionListener alis = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            changeLabel.setText(String.valueOf((char)labelAsciiValue++));
            }
        };

        buttonLabel.addActionListener(alis);

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(isBallRunning){
                    ba.stop();
                    button1.setText("Start");
                    isBallRunning = false;
                }else{
                    ba.start();
                    button1.setText("Stop");
                    isBallRunning = true;
                }
            }
        };
        button1.addActionListener(al);
    }
}
```